# Created emulator does not show in the toolbar

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I created an emulator through AVD Manager and can start it.

[image]
[image]

But I can not run the application on it, since it does not appear in toolbar, but I can run the exact emulator, without application in it, like in AVD Manager page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

[image: img'll help]
this issue normally comes in flutter. i hope the attached image